# Minimal symfony setup with annonations

Tags: symfony, annotations

i want to create a simple api based on Symfony framework.

The controllers are already implemented.

1) What is the minimal setup of composer packages i need?

2) How can i setup a working **index.php** file that creates the routes from the annotations, match the urls and outputs the response?

Thank you very much!

Here is an example code of one of my controllers located in **src/Bitter/Cloud/Server/Controller/PhotosController.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Bitter\Cloud\Server\Controller;

use Bitter\Cloud\Cloud;
use Bitter\Cloud\Services\PhotosService;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class PhotosController extends AbstractController
{
    protected Request $request;
    protected PhotosService $service;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $this->service = Cloud::getServices()->getPhotos();
    }

    /**
     * Send a request to fetch photos and videos from the photo service.
     *
     * @Route("/photos/get_photos")
     *
     * @link project://docs/services/photos/get-photos.md
     */
    public function getPhotos(): JsonResponse
    {
        $this->service->init();

        return new JsonResponse([
            "success" => true,
            "photos" => $this->service->getPhotos()
        ]);
    }
}
```

All other controllers are similar.

Here is my **composer.json** setup:

```
{
  "name": "bitter/cloud-server",
  "description": "Cloud Server for PHP.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "homepage": "*********removed*********",
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "*********removed*********",
      "email": "*********removed*********",
      "role": "Developer"
    }
  ],
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "name": "bitter/cloud-api",
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@bitbucket.org:*********removed*********"
    }
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "cloud",
    "php",
    "api"
  ],
  "support": {
    "issues": "*********removed*********"
  },
  "require": {
    "bitter/cloud-api": "*",
    "symfony/http-foundation": "5.0.0",
    "symfony/routing": "5.0.0",
    "symfony/config": "5.0.0",
    "doctrine/annotations": "1.8.0",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.0.0",
    "doctrine/cache": "1.8.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Bitter\\Cloud\\Server\\": "src/Bitter/Cloud/Server"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your example is using the Symfony framework controller so you may as well just use the Symfony framework skeleton as a starting point.  If you get away from the framework then you could reduce things a bit but it is doubtful that it would be worth the effort.  This is one of those questions that if you have to ask then you should not be doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is create a simple application with composer:

`composer create-project symfony/skeleton`

then add an annotations package:

`composer require annotations`

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution was what i'm looking for. And to all others thank you also for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to use API with composer the most know are https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/index.html fosRestBundle and https://symfony.com/projects/apiplatform it depends on your need the code you showed is a basic idea of an api

Answer (score 0):

[Apiplatform](https://api-platform.com/) might be your best solution to build an API based on Symfony, it is a full fledged system though (json, json+ld, graphql, auth, documentation, pagination, etc...).

Or if you just need a basic setup your solution might be fine (assuming you're using the [Symfony skeleton](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html)). Just setup routes in annotations in your controller and return data in JSON format.

As for the bundles you need it depends on what you want to able to achieve.
The [security bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) might be a good idea if you need authentication for instance. See [this doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html) to setup authentication for an API in Symfony.

The [maker bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html) is very useful to create entities and migrations. The [Doctrine ORM bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/index.html) is very handy to store and retrieve data from your database and maintain it. But it's all up to you to chose from these, see some [popular bundles](https://symfony.com/doc/bundles/) in Symfony.